# Express CORS server not sending cookie to client in production

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, cookies, cors

In development I am able to send cookies from the server (localhost:5000) to client (localhost:5173).

In production the server (https://task-x-server.onrender.com) cannot send cookies to the client (https://task-x-1.vercel.app). Here are all my settings involving routes/configuration of the server.

My client is ReactJS using axios for requests and Express is the server using passport for authentication

As you can see the client on my local machine receives the cookie:

[image: Localhost response headers]

[image: Localhost request header]

[image: set-cookie localhost]

The production build doesn't:

[image: prod response headers]

[image: prod request headers]

[image: set-cookie-headers]

**Server:**

**index.ts**

```
import cors from "cors";
import helmet from "helmet";
import getCookies from "./middlewares/getCookies";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";


app.use(helmet({ crossOriginResourcePolicy: { policy: "cross-origin" } }));

app.use(cors({ origin: clientUrl, credentials: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(getCookies);

googleAuthRoutes(app);
```

**getCookies.ts** - this middleware takes all cookies and appends them to req.cookies:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

const getCookies = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const cookies = req.headers.cookie;

  if (cookies) {
    const values = cookies.split(";").reduce((res, item) => {
      const data = item.trim().split("=");

      return { ...res, [data[0] as string]: data[1] };
    }, {});

    req.cookies = values;
  }

  next();
};

export default getCookies;
```

**requireJwt.ts** - this function verifies the JWT token that is inside the cookie:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";
import keys from "../config/keys";
import types from "../types/express";

export const requireJwt = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;

  const { jwtSecret, clientUrl } = keys;

  try {
    const { user } = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret) as JwtPayload;
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.clearCookie("token");
    res.status(401).send({ error: "You must be logged in" });
    res.redirect(clientUrl);
  }
};

export default requireJwt;
```

**authRoutes.ts** - One route logs the user in and sets the JWT in the cookie. The next route verifies the cookie and sends the user object in response.

```
import passport from "passport";
import { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import requireJwt from "../middlewares/requireJwt";

const googleAuthRoutes = (app: Express) => {
  app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      session: false,
    }),
    (req, res) => {

      const { user } = req;

      const token = jwt.sign({ user }, *jwtSecret*, {
        expiresIn: "1d",
      });

      res.cookie("token", token, {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        expires: dayjs().add(1, "day").toDate(),
      });

      res.redirect(`${clientUrl}/setup`);
    })

     app.get("/api/current_user", requireJwt, (req, res) => {
       res.send(req.user);
     });
  }
```

**Client**:

**api/index.ts**:

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import keys from "../config/keys";

axios.defaults.baseURL = keys.server;

export const axiosFetchUser = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/current_user`, {
    withCredentials: true,
  });

  return data;
};
```

**App.tsx** - where the fetchUser is being called:

```
import { ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Landing from "./landing/Landing";
import ProfileSetup from "./profile/profile-setup/ProfileSetup";

const App = (): ReactElement => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppThunkDispatch>();
  const [user, setUser] - useState()

  useEffect(() => {
   //axiosFetchUser call
  }, []);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
      <Route path="/setup" element={<ProfileSetup />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your two screenshots show requests, not responses. Also, instead of describing what your client does, why don't you show the code?

Comment: @jub0bs all done can you review it again please?

Comment: I'd like to see the response that sets the cookie in question. What does the `Set-Cookie` header look like?

Comment: @jub0bs sorry I should have know that. I have added those into the document too, please review it for me

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything amiss.